# Is there a relatively inexpensive form of double sided tape that would be safe to use (i.e., low static) for mounting a sensor?

Tags: sensor, antistatic, adhesives

Apologies in advance if this question would be best directed elsewhere:

I am working on a wearable project, and would like to attach two small IMUs ( [see product page here](https://www.pololu.com/product/2738/%22here%22)) to some fabric.  Each sensor has only one mounting hole, and so thread alone has been insufficient to provide a secure attachment.  I was considering switching to something adhesive, and asked the representatives from the store that sells the sensor what they might recommend.  They suggested double sided tape, but cautioned that anything cellophane-based might pose an ESD risk.

My question: What kind of double sided tape might be safe to use for my project?

I've done a search for anti-static tape, and am not sure how to evaluate the very wide range of options that appear to be available.  Ideally, I could find something at a relatively low cost, and I am not looking for a super strong hold (this is just a simple prototype, and I'd like the option of repositioning the sensors if I need to).

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: you left out a very important piece of information .... what are you attaching to?

Comment: You can probably use heatsink tape. Example: 3M 8805 tape. I would expect that this is static safe since it is used to attach heatsinks to IC's.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies!  To jsotola: I'm currently attaching the sensors to armbands made from nylon straps.

Comment: 3m double sided sticky tape

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use ESD Kapton Polyamide tape single sided tape.

1. Seal all exposed surfaces and conductor joints
2. Use for adhesive to material

http://www.tapemarket.com/esd_tape.htm

Warning : it is not really cheap but that is what is used in PCB industry. Banggood has it.

If you really want double sided tape. So be it but then you risk non conductive high e-field damage.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick reply.  I would be interested to better understand the details of the risk that you describe for the double-sided tape, though I'm also happy to go read any reference material, if that would be a better way to pick up the relevant knowledge.

Comment: Search for e-field EOS in high impedance circuits